# Dealing with typescript types, react, webGL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webgl

I'm having trouble controlling types while following a tutorial on webGL. Specifically, I am being forced to wrap many of my arguments in `if(gl.something !== null) { }` to guard it, otherwise typescript throws errors along the lines of `TS2345: Argument of type 'WebGLProgram | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebGLProgram'`

My react app is written like so:

```
function App() {

    const canvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

    useEffect(()=> webglStuff(canvas),[]
    )

  return (
      <div>
        <div>hey mate</div>
          <canvas ref={canvas} width="450" height="250">Browser no good mate</canvas>
          <div>bye mate</div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

if I remove the initial value of `null` from the `useRef` method, I receive the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>'.   Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
```

However, I keep having to deal with the problem of `gl`'s children possibly being null. I have the following function in which I have had to wrap sections in `if (gl.something !== null){ }`, and I would prefer not to:

```
const webglStuff = (canvas: RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>)=> {

    const gl = canvas.current!.getContext('webgl2')
        if(gl !== null && gl !== undefined) {   //     <-- here

            const program = gl.createProgram()

            ...
            ...

            const program = gl.createProgram(); //     <-- here
            if (program !== null) {
               gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
               gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
               gl.linkProgram(program);
               if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                   console.error("ERROR linking program", gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))
                   return
               }
            }
         }
}}
```